# Malicious Mass Email Attack Occurred, Do I Still Have Problem?

Tags: email, man-in-the-middle, apache, email-spoofing, smtp

I'm using Apache Airflow and I was troubleshooting built-in smtp setup. A mass email occurred on "ops@myexample.com". It was used as a "From:" email in a mass email attack.

**Chronology:** Started docker by running an extended build on apache/airflow:2.5.2-python3.7. Purchased "ops@myexample.com" from gmail business email. Added a custom gmail "App Password". Added smtp parameters for this email in airflow.cfg. Enabled IMAP access in gmail. And  I got a successful email working via scheduled airflow DAG.

After successful email, I noticed there were 5-10 mass emails being sent every minute "From:ops@myexample.com". Definitely not me.

**Takeaways/Concerns:**

I should have setup wireshark when the email attack was happening to monitor if the emails were coming from my ethernet, but I didn't think to do this straightaway. I disabled gmail IMAP, changed passwords in configs and on gmail, and shut down docker. After I shut everything down, I tried to reboot my docker setup with wireshark smtp monitor to see if mass email attack was coming from my setup. The attack stopped and I never saw fraudulent smtp activity from my ethernet (but again I wasn't quick enough to do it while occurring).

Is this a "man-in-the-middle" attack? How do I prevent this if so?

If I had to diagnose, the malicious actor sniffed "ops@myexample.com" gmail somehow and was not on my personal computer. They used my gmail to execute the mass email attack but were never locally on my machine. I really hope this is the case. However, I'm worried the malicious actor may have got on my computer or in my docker setup somehow and my computer may be compromised.

Perhaps I built a docker image that has been infiltrated with a bad actor... perhaps there is a compromised element in apache/airflow:2.5.2-python3.7 ?

Comment: From the receiving end of one of these message, you might want to take a look at the headers of the message, and this will show you the IP address of the sending SMTP server of the message.  From this, you'll be able to see if it was sent from 'your ethernet' or from your docker setup, or from some other source.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful and I didn't think to do that. It does seem that the emails are coming from a different IP in singapore/netherlands. >>>
On the bad emails, I see the likes of: Received: from DESKTOP-3VDCBV6 ([193.37...IP])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id u9-20020a17090228900b001a9sm6323340plr.21.2023.04.16.16.31.05
<<<
This is NOT my info and it is NOT my IP. So, it looks like it was coming from a different computer and not own. Any other things to check or helpful security feedback?

Comment: It seems that the malicious actor may be spoofing these emails with your address (ops@myexample.com) as the sender address, then sending these emails from their IP address (193.37.*.*), through Gmail's outgoing SMTP service.  But, the concern here is the actor may have your credentials for Gmail's outgoing SMTP service, in order for him/her to do this - as I don't believe Gmail will allow emails purportedly from ops@myexample.com to be sent through their outgoing SMTP service, unless the credentials associated with this address are used to authenticate.  You might want to change these ASAP.

Comment: I had this included in my initial writeup but StackExchange blocked for being too much like "spam":  After noticin the malicious emails, I immediately filled out a gmail fraud report, disabled IMAP, changed my password, disabled my app password, shut down and deleted my docker setup. Emails didn't stop immediately after doing this and continued on for 3-4 mins longer. I hope the delay was due to things in flight. I changed my smtp email setup from "SSL" to "TSL" (I thought SSL was more secure but turns on TSL is more secure). I changed my docker passwords and my google passwords as well.

Comment: Hopefully the changes that you made have put an end to the problem.  The 3-4 minute interval that you saw could just be from deferrals and requeing.  Out of curiosity, was your system sending outgoing emails using Gmail's outgoing SMTP server at [smtp.gmail.com](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp)?  If so, was it connecting to smtp.gmail.com on port 465 (using SSL), or was it connecting to smtp.gmail.com on port 587 (using STARTTLS)?

Comment: I updated the smtp variables in airflow.cfg. At first, I had "smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com; smtp_starttls = false; smtp_ssl = true; smtp_port = 465". Then I updated to what I believe is more secure: "smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com; smtp_starttls = true; smtp_ssl = false; smtp_port = 587".  Any tips on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a lot of confusion around the terms SSL and TLS.  In reality, TLS is a newer and more secure version of SSL, but often the two terms are used interchangeably (as Gmail does in the link above).  To make it even more confusing, we also have STARTTLS, which is where the connection starts off without any encryption, then the connection is upgraded to use TLS to secure the connection.  It sounds like STARTTLS was what you were using at first.

Comment: STARTTLS is vulnerable to downgrade attacks. Although unlikely, if the attacker was in a position to tamper with the connection from your system to smtp.gmail.com, then it's possible that he/she could have pulled off such an attack to intercept your credentials.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/205775/tls-downgrade-attacks and https://words.filippo.io/the-sad-state-of-smtp-encryption/ for some interesting reading on this subject.  You're better off connecting to smtp.gmail.com on port 587 using SSL (aka TLS) if your client supports it.

Comment: A phrase you need to know that might explain what you saw (and what you need to block): "Open Relay"

Comment: I think you're right @BenVoigt ... it does seem to be in this open relay attack format. I'll see about conducting testing for it.